# using pangolin library in android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, pangolin

I want to implement Orb slam2 of [raulmur](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) on android. Orb slam2 use [pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin)  that is in c++ language but pangolin library not be used on android up to now and I can't find any example of android project that used pangolin.

My question is this: If we can build pangolin for ndk and use it in project ,how the output map that is made by pangolin will monitor for user?this question is from this fact that an android app gui is by java. is there any function that we use it in layout file and can monitor the build map?

in this [repo](https://github.com/FireStoneYS/ORB_SLAM2_Android) and this [one](https://github.com/muziyongshixin/ORB-SLAM2-based-AR-on-Android)  Orbslam2 of Raulmur has been implemented on android but map building section is ignored and None of them have used pangolin.